# Section not showing background color

Tags: html, css

I have tried this very same method on a previous website in which it worked. I am not sure why isn't it working now.

```css
body {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#header_encapsulator {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: orange;
}
header {
position: fixed;
max-width: 60em;
width: 100%;
}
.logo {
float: left;
font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive; 
font-size: 3rem;
padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
nav {
float: right;
padding: 1.5rem 1rem 0 0;
}
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:first-child {
padding-right: .8rem;
}

h1 {
font-size: 2rem;
text-align: center;
padding: 12rem 0 2rem 0;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_encapsulator">
  <header>
    <a class="logo" href="/">Logo_name</a>
    <nav>
      <a href="">Menu_1</a>
      <a href="">Menu_2</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

I am not sure why `margin:auto` inside `#header_encapsulator` doesn't center `<header>` if I don't specify a `max-width`. The website will break on a monitor with >1000px width. It doesn't take 10000px value not does it take % values too.

Secondly, the `header_encapsulator` should show a orange background image edge to edge of the display. It doesn't show. I know that empty divs/sections doesn't display it's properties, but I have done it before, the exact same way.

Edit:
I have created a simpler html and css file with the same code. You can download it [here](https://mega.nz/#F!epUzHK6Q!J39FPQ6h2ypsy_MleliKJA) and test it locally. I don't get the orange background 100% of the monitor width.

Comment: clear your cache and refresh, it works on my test

Comment: Tried it, no luck

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/TrustworthyBronzeSymbol

Comment: It's a basic static website. The console is empty except for a warning regarding character encoding.

Comment: Please verify that your stylesheet is loading, press ctrl+u and try clicking the link in the `<link>` tag or check for errors in the developer console. Also try ctrl+shift+r to do a hard refresh.

Comment: The style sheet is loading.. Everything css is seen on the page except this background.

Comment: is there any css for header or a or nav? maybe those have backgrounds with overlays the header_encapsulator background

Comment: Yes, there is css for header and other elements inside. I'll post it in the main question.

Comment: posted an answer please verify if it helps thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there's any reason to have the `#header-encapsulator` not being fixed itself instead of the header inside (which causes the encapsulator to be "empty", thus, not having a height), but simply moving the `position: fixed` property to `#header-encapsulator`and adding a `width: 100%` should fix the issue

Edit: Removed 10000px max-width property from #header_encapsulator and width:100% from header.

```css
body {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header_encapsulator {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  /*Put it in here*/
  position: fixed;
}

header {
  /*Removed it from here*/
  max-width: 60em;
  margin:auto
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem 0 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:first-child {
  padding-right: .8rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12rem 0 2rem 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_encapsulator">
  <header>
    <a class="logo" href="/">Logo_name</a>
    <nav>
      <a href="">Menu_1</a>
      <a href="">Menu_2</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Comment: @mjustin given the changes made; I'd definitely recommend taking some time to rethink a bit the structure you have built, since setting a `max-width: 10000px`, or any other property with values without concrete meaning is not a good practice... Maybe you can find a way to tweak the structure a bit to avoid such a large number and use something that makes more sense and makes everything work smoothly.

Comment: I removed that 10000px. It is no more required. And yes, I strongly feel against such vague properties. This was the first time I ever used it as a part of tinkering cos the whole things was going south from the start. :) Thanks to you and everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `max-width: 100%`.
This is the **maximum** width that will be taken up by the `div` and in order to reach this width, the `div` element will require enough content to fill it to 100%.

Use `width` instead of `max-width`. This will force any div to be the specified width, regardless of content.

Comment: Tried it, still no luck. I also tried max-width: 1000px and width: 100% at the same time. Yet, no luck.

Comment: Make sure you hold ctrl while clicking refresh. If you don't, the browser will keep the cached CSS file and it will appear as though nothing has changed(ctrl refresh for chrome, use ctrl+shift+R for firefox).

Comment: I went ahead as far as deleting all personal data, history, cookies etc from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Give a height to your #header_encapsulator like so:

```
#header_encapsulator {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px; // or anything you want
}
```

plus if you want margin: auto header you should do something like:

```
#header_encapsulator header {
  margin: auto;
//other css if you want
}
```

Comment: Yet, it doesn't stretch 1000px, even if I change to width:1000px or max-width: 1000px and width: 100%

Comment: you should use width: 1000px to make sure it is stretched as much as you want. I update the answer now.

Comment: Tried last time itself, doesn't work. I had mentioned in the comment that it doesn't work even if I change to width:1000px. I have uploaded the files to test it locally https://mega.nz/#F!epUzHK6Q!J39FPQ6h2ypsy_MleliKJA

Comment: Yes, it works there. What's even more frustrating is the there is this same piece of code in another project and it works fine now when I check it.